# Can't find my model

Tags: 3d-view, objects

I somehow lost my model. My view in default moved so far away and I can't find my model in the blender world. I can see it in 3D full view, so I know the model's still there, but in that I can't move objects. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the blender world"?

Comment: I mean basically in blender. In the scene. Whatever.

Comment: but you said that you can see it in the 3D view, so where is it lost?

Comment: in default view

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you can see your object, but you can't select it? If that's the case, make sure it is set as selectable in the outliner.

Comment: No. In the default view, I can't find my model. I can see it in Animation view, and all the other views though.

Comment: Good Call to put this on hold.  Cooperation is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Be in object mode. Select in outliner window is possible .Then try these

- Select any object (not camera) .. press Numeric Keypad . (period next to zero)
- Select One or More Objects.  Press the Home Key ... there are two Home Keys on a  full Keyboard. Choose Home ... Next to the the PageUp Key.
- Select the camera. Grab Z Z ...keystrokes GZZ. Move your mouse to move the camera closer.  Control Alt Number (Keypad) 0 ... will align the view.

With the mouse wheel scroll to zoom.

Keep in mind as you move the view with your mouse you are in USER VIEW.  Pressing numpad 0 puts you in CAMERA VIEW.  Numpad 0 switches back and forth.

I suggest you see a worthwhile tutorial video on a video site such as youtube as a random and known site.  Search Blender 2.7 Tutorial Introduction.

Here is a nice one
 -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlj_4nlJWpo

Comment: Waitasec. Select a vertex in 3d full view. Go into default view. Press home key. Zoom. Said top persp but didn't work for me. I couldn't do the first paragraph because when I go in to object mode, and select something, I can't get back in to edit mode.

Comment: Ok. Actually, numpad 0 showed me the model, but everything's gray except for that orange box. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: @user6383 The orange box just means the object is selected.

Comment: Nooooooooo. When you press numpad 0. It's not actually orange, just lighter than the rest of the screen. The camera view.

Comment: What's outliner?

Answer (score 3):

Just select the object in the outliner panel (top right in default view) and hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the properties panel. The very top of this panel should say 'Transform'. Set all the values to '0'.

If the object still doesn't show, there are a couple things to check:

**1**. Make sure you are in the right scene.

**2**. Make sure you didn't delete the item.

**3**. Make sure the item is marked as 'visible'(eye icon) in the Outliner.
Hope this works for you.:)

*If your view is to far <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>(view selected) should fix that.*

Also try checking / unchecking LOCK TO CURSOR

Answer (score 1):

Select the object in the Outliner and press Alt+G that resets the location (to the center). This way you might see your model again.