# How find objects in the 3D view?

Tags: 3d-view

I was using the fly settings and I got too fast. I left the fly mode and i don't know how to get back. I cannot find my project as I am to far away. How can I locate my project?

Comment: Maybe related Q...[Can't find my model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16521/cant-find-my-model)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to fix this.

If you select an object in your project, you can do do `View > Frame Selected` to center your viewport on that object.

Alternatively, `View > Frame All` Will move your viewport to be centered looking at all the objects in your scene.